# How can I detect java version used to compile .jasper?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a bunch of .jasper file which I have no idea which java version has been used to compile them.

**Is there any way to detect it?**

For java class I know dat we can use follwing command.

```
javap -verbose .\Customer.class | findstr "major"
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below steps to find the Jasper Report version:

1. Navigate to the path $DCS/server/run/jrtskdae/lib/
2. Search for **jasperreports**
3. The version of the jasperreports.jar file is the version of the Jasper Reports being used by the product
   *(eg. **jasperreports-5.0.0.jar**)*

Comment: `The version of the jasperreports.jar file is the version of the Jasper Reports being used by the product` - How this related with *jasper* file that can be created by 3rd party?

Comment: I have just a bunch of `filename.jasper` and nothing more.

Comment: @AlexK
I don't have access to the path `$DCS/server/run/jrtskdae/lib/` as you mentioned on your answer, I have just a files. Also consider that I am not looking for Jasper Report version but java verion which has been used to compile the `file.jasper`

Comment: @itro It is not my answer